# How do I embed a Tweet in TinyMCE cloud

Tags: twitter, media

I can't seem to embed tweets in TinyMCE. I tried using the Insert Media function and I can get it to pull in text and links but no photos/videos. Is this possible?

I tried using Insert Media and also adding it in the HTML and neither would load a tweet.